# How to interpret coefficient and marginal effect in probit when $\beta$ is not identified

Tags: interpretation, probit, identifiability, marginal-effect

Say we have the latent variable $y_i^*=x_i\beta-\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

$y_i^*/\sigma=x_i\beta/\sigma-u_i$ where $u_i=\epsilon_i/\sigma \sim N(0, 1)$, and so can use Probit to estimate this regression.

$$
Pr(y_i=1|x_i) = Pr(y_i^*>0) = Pr(x_i\beta<\epsilon_i)=\Phi(x_i\beta/\sigma)
$$
Thus, $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are not identified. The identified ones are $\beta/\sigma$.

In turn, the size of coefficients in the regression outputs cannot be interpreted, but the significance level is still correct about $\beta$ because the test statistics $=\frac{(\beta/\sigma)-0}{\sqrt{var(\beta/\sigma})}=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{var(\beta)}}$. Is this correct?

Second, how to interpret the marginal effect is $\beta/\sigma \phi(x_i\beta/\sigma)$? I used to interpret average marginal effect, for example, the AME=0.1, then if $x$ increases by 1, the probability of $y_i=1$ increase by 0.1. Is this still correct if $\beta$ is not identified?